# How can I prevent the change event from firing when setting state in Bootstrap Switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my document.ready I am setting this control to a `bootstrapSwitch` and setting the state based on data from a database. Setting that state fires off the `change switchChange.bootstrapSwitch`. Is there anyway I can set it so it will not fire off a event? I have tried to change it to a click event but that is not working. Any help would be great I just want the click event when the users selects the control.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#IsPublish").bootstrapSwitch();
  $("#IsPublish").bootstrapSwitch('state', true);
});

$('#IsPublish').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#status').text('click');
});

$('#IsPublish').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  //$('#status').text('switchChange');  
});

$('#IsPublish').change('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  //$('#status').text('change'); 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css" integrity="sha512-lANJTDwF23Xos7T5Q7SNbZ7dFxLG8YSQJ2qCGrav0Fhe5vns60+tUECZv+9udXdKiX3/YTWt++tEKyEcuZv4dQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="checkbox" id="IsPublish" />
<br><br>
<label id="status"></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info), about your proposed solution instead of your problem. You should be asking how to set state on initialization. You can do that with the `state` option property, which eliminates the event in the later state update you had been using.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#IsPublish").bootstrapSwitch({
    'state': true
  });
});

$('#IsPublish').on('click', function(event) {
  $('#status').text('click');
});

$('#IsPublish').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  console.log('changed in on()');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css" integrity="sha512-lANJTDwF23Xos7T5Q7SNbZ7dFxLG8YSQJ2qCGrav0Fhe5vns60+tUECZv+9udXdKiX3/YTWt++tEKyEcuZv4dQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"
  referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input type="checkbox" id="IsPublish" />
<br><br>
<label id="status"></label>
```